# Text not resized when changing slide size

Tags: resize, powerpoint

I would have a noob question about PowerPoint resizing.
I have a slide in "On screen Show (16:9)" size that I need to resize in "Widescreen" size, which is still 16:9 ratio but not the same dimensions.
So I changed the "Slide Size" option : the pictures are well resized, but the text font size in texboxes has not been changed proportionnaly.
My initial slide looks like this :
[before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jddTf.jpg)
But after resizing, the text font size in textboxes has not been changed :
[after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdE1R.jpg)

Would anyone have a solution to resize the same way all the element of a slide, including text ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally, users want the type to remain the same height, since resizing maintains the same at the same height (7.5"). Only the width changes. You could write a macro to reduce the text size by a proportionate amount.

Comment: Thank you.  What is surprising is that all textboxes are not treated the same way : most of texts are not resized, but some others are, according to the correct ratio.   I don't know how I will manage to write a macro that can distinguish the text to modify.

Comment: I don't see text getting resized under any circumstances. If you see that, then you'll have to figure out what is different about those shapes than others. Feel free to upload your file that shows that to a cloud service, then post a share link here. I take a look.

Comment: You can notice that between my 2 screenshots, [before resizing]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/jddTf.jpg) and [after resizing]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdE1R.jpg), the words "Erreur Absolue" have been correctly resized, as opposed to the words "Slant Distance". I don't know why, because both are in a textbox. 
But I have a lead : I noticed that a textbox with the option "Shrink text on overflow" activated seems to be correctly resized. I am now searching for a VBA code that activate this option for all textboxes in my PowerPoint document.

Comment: I thank you for your help. I will post my new question in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I try this VBA code to have all textboxes with the option "Shrink text on overflow" :

```
Sub Change()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
       oshape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape 
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

But that unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: John Korchok kindly answered my question in another thread that I opened for that.